# Tall Citrus tree is more like a leggy bush

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, citrus

I have 5 citrus trees that I inherited from the previous homeowners. Two are mandarin orange trees. (One tastes like delicious candy. The other needs some help, as it's dry.) There's also an orange (?) tree that has a TON of fruit on it, but tastes bitter and dry. It looked like a mandarin orange tree at first, but now the fruit definitely looks like an orange. I'll keep researching those non-tasty trees, but the question I have for now are about these other TWO citrus trees on the property that look more like bushes. I'm showing you an example of the taller, bigger one. The smaller one has the same characteristics of the tall one. The limbs are super long, and droop a bit, they have thorns. It doesn't stand tall like a tree. When it rains (rarely here in Los Angeles) they fall over almost to the ground. There's no real trunk, just a bunch of skinny limbs coming out from the ground. Not sure what it is, what to do with it, or if it can be groomed into a real citrus tree. (Is that a thing?) I haven't seen any fruit on it, but I do see a few blossoms on it. I'm also a newbie in the citrus tree arena. So this all a learning experience for me. Pics attached. Any advice would be so helpful! Thanks!

[image: Leaves]

[image: Trunk]

[image: Tall Bush-like Citrus Tree]

Comment: The first picture has a leaf that looks a lot like Kaffir lime

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find what your looking for here.
https://www.selfsufficientme.com/fruit-vegetables/what-s-wrong-with-my-lemon-tree-the-fruit-tastes-awful

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Thanks so much! This was tremendously helpful.

Comment: Glad i could help. Hope your trees return back to their former selves.